# How to make ListView items arrange in grid format

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I want to display a list of items in a table like format.  The format is fluid such that if a user resizes then more or less items will display on a row.  I want to replicate how floated divs display within a container.

How do I do this in WPF?

So far I can get the items to display in a vertical format but cant figure out what to do next.  P.s. for now I am hard coding the items whilst I debug, but I will bind it to a list at some point.

```
    <ListView>
        <ListViewItem Width="244">
            <local:ScheduledRecordingView />
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem Width="244">
            <local:ScheduledRecordingView />
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: GridView  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [WrapPanel as ItemPanel for ItemsControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131919/wrappanel-as-itempanel-for-itemscontrol)

Answer (score 1):

Surely been asked before, please search before asking.

Just make the [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) a [`WrapPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx). If you don't create a specific [`View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.view.aspx) (not necessary here) you should use a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) or if you don't need selection either an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx).

Comment: I did search... but all the results came back for Grids so couldnt figure out what to search for - sometimes not knowing what to look for is the problem :)

Comment: @Chris: Well, that is true.